# 'QString' object does not support item assignment python

Tags: python, time, pyqt4, maya

```
self.date = QtCore.QDate.currentDate() 
self.time = QtCore.QTime.currentTime()
self.updateTime = QtCore.QString(self.time.toString("hh:mm:ss AP"))
if ((self.time.second() % 2) == 0):
    self.updateTime[2]= ' '

self.label.setText(self.updateTime)

Error: TypeError: file line 54: 'QString' object does not support item assignment
```

iam getting this error in if loop, is there any solution? iam new to python any help appreciated....

thank you

Comment: Your question would have been much better if you'd asked: in my clock widget, how do I make the ":" blink on and off every other second? Instead, your question currently amounts to little more than a trivial bit of debugging that can be easily solved by consulting the relevant documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you cannot change the the `QString` by item assignment (`a[2] = ' '`); you get a `TypeError` whenever you try to do something to an object that isn't allowed.  You have to create a new string and assign it to the variable.  So, replace the line

```
self.updateTime[2]= ' '
```

with the following

```
self.updateTime = self.updateTime[:2] + ' ' +self.updateTime[3:]
```