# 'QString' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, qstring

There is  something [similar to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299437/qstring-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-python) but I am still confused about it.

Here is the part of the  code:

```
class General(Component):
    def __init__(self, localvars,globalvars,coupledvars,outputvars,equation):

        self.loc = localvars

        for i in range(0,len(localvars)):
            localvars[i] = Float(1.0, iotype='in')
        print localvars
```

Comment: [Q]Strings are immutable

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['QString' object does not support item assignment python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23299437/qstring-object-does-not-support-item-assignment-python)